# Absolute rest in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

I am new to special relativity and with still little experience in Physics. I would like to know why a privileged frame of reference that determines absolute rest is not possible. I want you to explain to me what is wrong in the following thought experiment.

An empty universe in which there are only two bodies of the same mass separated from each other and approaching each other. In principle, it would not be possible for an observer to distinguish which of the two bodies is the one that is moving and which is the one that is still. What we can know is its time dilation. Dilation increases as speed increases. In that sense we could know which of the two experiences more dilation and therefore which of the two moves at a faster speed. Once this is understood, now comes the important thing.

Imagine a single object in the universe, we can give it all the "nudges" we want. With this, its speed would vary depending on where we hit it and the force we use. If we hit it infinite times in different places and with different forces, there will be a moment where it will reach all possible speeds. In each state or speed we measure its time dilation and the one in which the value is less will be the point of absolute rest since there is no other point where the dilation is less.

Comment: "Dilation increases as speed increases". Nope. Not true. What is true is that "Dilation increases as _relative_ speed increases".

Comment: "Dilation increases as speed increases.".  Do you mean **absolute** speed?  If so, you are implicitly assuming (falsely) that absolute speed is meaningful, which makes it unsurprising that you are able to conclude that absolute speed is meaningful.  Or do you perhaps mean speed **relative to you**?  In that case, yes, your method will totally work to discover which objects are at rest relative to you.  But there are, of course, much easier ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, your idea is incorrect. Time dilation is relative. If two objects are moving relative to each other, each object will be time dilated to the same extent relative to the other. If you perform your experiment, the object will be least time dilated according to you when it is stationary in your frame. If I am moving relative to you, and I perform the experiment, I will conclude that the object is least time dilated when it is stationary relative to me.